# what is max count for instagram get recent media api?

Tags: instagram-api

In Instagram api documentation, for api GET/users/user-id/media/recent
it doesn't mention what is max count supported for each api call.
Does anyone has idea about it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

<s>It appears there is no limit for /users/user-id/media/recent - at least I just ran this and got 5500+ results back for user '787132' (natgeo).</s> If you want to limit it use the count parameter.
Note that other endpoints seem to have limits e.g. /media/popular will usually return a max of 20.
Also be aware that if you do not limit using the count param you might reach your global / endpoint specific rate limit as per http://instagram.com/developer/limits/

Comment: @RocketR yes you are right, thanks! I must have been making repeated API calls. Default (no count param) seems to be 20.

Comment: It has been a little over two years and it seems that Instagram has limited the max count to be 20 regardless if you put 25, or 33. Just in case anyone else is searching this currently.

Comment: I’m only able to retrieve a max of 6 now, as of March 28, 2018, and the docs page is down. Perhaps this is part of their move to the Instagram Graph API?